# Use Jquery to create an element with escaped text + HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-escape-characters

Here is what I am trying to produce:

```
"<td>"+name+"<textarea>"+content+"</textarea></td>";
```

I know jQuery can escape using:

```
jQuery("<td>", name)
```

But how do you incorporate some html in addition to it?

Comment: You append new elements to it

Comment: Incorporate HTML where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to create DOM elements and their properties/attributes dynamically with something like the following...

```
var name = 'name';
var content = 'content';

var $td = $('<td>', {
  html: $('<textarea>', {
    rows: 5
  }).text(content)
}).prepend(name);
```